# Entity Framework with NuGet - Import-Module error in init.ps1

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-4.3

Here is the complete error message that I get in the Package Manager Console when starting VS2010:

> Import-Module : The specified module
>   'C:\Users\adam.assman\Project\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools\EntityFramework.psd1'
>   was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
>   directory. At
>   C:\Users\adam.assman\Project\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools\init.ps1:13
>   char:14

I've installed Entity Framework using NuGet, on a DLL/ClassLibrary project in my solution. The startup project is referencing and using this DLL project. I therefore tried running the startup command from the console with the DLL project selected in the dropdown "Default Project", but that gives me the same error message.

I have NuGet version 1.6.21215.9133 (and obviously EF version 4.3.1).

If I try to run the command "Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations", I get a `CommandNotFoundException` and I suppose it's a result from the init error. I'm trying to accomplish the simplest form of the automatic migrations, using this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Do other module-based packages work? (e.g. MvcScaffolding) If not, there may be something wrong with your system's PowerShell configuration.

Comment: If there was a problem with my PowerShell config (which I have never configurated myself), how could that be reset?

Comment: Possibly by re-installing/repairing [PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) or by verifying your [PowerShell profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613488.aspx).

Comment: I have the same problem with latest version of EF and powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what was wrong, but I finally fixed this by editing the file `init.ps1` inside the folder `\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools`.

I changed this line:

```
Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath 'EntityFramework.psd1') -ArgumentList $installPath
```

Into this:

```
Import-Module '.\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\tools\EntityFramework.psd1' -ArgumentList $installPath
```